# how to give underline to whole div tag in jsp?

Tags: html, css, jsp

I am using bootstrap . My jsp code is :

```
   <div class="form-group"><label class="col-md-1 col-md-offset-1 control-label"> Name:</label>
                                            <div class="col-md-5">
                                                <font style="text-decoration: underline;"><%=name%></font>
                                            </div>
```

Here name is dynamic as per table in database.If name is abc then it gives underline only abc .But I want underline to for whole div tag.
Please help me.

Thanks

Comment: You know `text-decoration: underline;` is only for text right? If you want to "underline" the div you must give it a `border-bottom`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe put a `border-bottom` CSS attribute of the `div` i.e

```
div.form-group{
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}
```

Also, you may want to re-consider your use of the `font` element: [Font HTML Element](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_font.asp).

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for it:-

```
.form-group{border-bottom:1px solid #333}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/THE_MukulKant/52VtD/8986/)

Answer (score 0):

```css
.form-group > div, .form-group > label {
  text-decoration: underline;
  float: left;
 }
.control-label {
  float: left;
 }
```

```html
<div class="form-group"><label class="col-md-1 col-md-offset-1 control-label"> Name:</label>
                                            <div class="col-md-5">
                                                <font style="text-decoration: underline;"><%=name%></font>
                                            </div>
```